# IIS Recycling too often

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2003

We run a .NET 1.1 application on W2k3 server. The app pool is configured to recycle at 512MB. However, a week ago it started to recycle every 2 minutes. Since we run a web farm, the anonymous user we run IIS with is a domain account.
About a week ago, that user account expired, and we have to re-enable it. Could that have caused any problems? Maybe that user lost some permissions, or was left out of the IIS_WPG group.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try finding out more info by [Logging ASP.NET Application Shutdown Events](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Look in the server's Event Log. That may hold the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If after checking the logs and all the standard "App Pool Health" settings (the obvious), I would look for other processes that might be mucking around with your web.config file (check the timestamp on it), which of course causes the app to restart.

I was once at a customer site and we couldn't figure out why our app kept restarting (and dropping all session state, etc...)  Turned out it was a broken "Auto-Encrypt All Web.Config Files" little script that they had scheduled to run every 5 minutes.  Problem was it never properly detected that it successfully had encrypted the file, so it just kept rewriting every 5 minutes... sigh..